# Deny access to subfolder and file with .htaccess

Tags: apache-httpd, htaccess, rewrite

I need to deny access to configuration files under some subfolder. Currently I have this rule but it doesn't work:

```
<Files ~ "((foo|bar))$">
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

If I go to `www.mysite.com/foo/foo2/file.xml`, I can view the file. I need to deny all file accesses into `foo`and `bar` recursively

**UPDATE**

I have tried this this configuration but have an Internal Error

```
<FilesMatch ".foo\.(*)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 2):

"`<Files>` [...] will be applied to any object with a basename (last component of filename) matching the specified filename".
It's not what you want.

`Directory*` don't work in `.htaccess`

You have to use `mod_rewrite`.
For example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(foo|bar) - [F]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of file directive try using location :

```
<Location "path/to/folder-or-file">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Location>
```

Comment: The Location directive isn't valid in .htaccess files, as the author requested.  This will cause a 500 error.

Answer (score 1):

I would do regex matching inside the apache config. Then

- use `<DirectoryMatch>` instead of `<File>` (you are regular expression matching on a directory)
- correct your regex's strictness (specifically the `$`)
- simplify your regex (too many brackets)

  ```
  <DirectoryMatch "/path/to/toplevel/(foo|bar)">
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all
  </DirectoryMatch>
  ```

Note that `/path/to/toplevel/` is the file system location of your WWW directory where `foo` and `bar` reside.

---

However, If you want to do it via `.htaccess` only, create a `.htaccess` file in **every** directory that you want to deny (foo, bar, foo/bar etc), and put the line

```
Deny from all
```

inside.

Comment: If i use DirectoryMatch like you have described, i have Internal Server Error,  the folder are in the same directory oh .htacces (/)

Comment: Are you doing this via the `.htaccess` file? In which case you will require `AllowOverride Limit` set on that directory by your main apache configuration.

Comment: Yes, i need put into .htaccess file, i have `AllowOverride All` in apache configuration

Comment: What is your apache error log showing?

Comment: `DirectoryMatch not allowed here`

Comment: It has to be inside your main apache config.

Comment: To the title i have specified "whit .htaccess"

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: Yes i know, but i need make an unique .htaccess file, i resolved partially with `RewriteRule ^foo(/|$) - [L,NC]` , now i have a `Forbidden` to directory  but i can view the files inside directories foo/foo2/file.xml (example)

Comment: You need the .htaccess file inside foo/foo2 (as they are not recursively applied), hence the suggestion to do it more cleanly inside the apache config.